# am getting error with android studio R.java

Tags: java, html, r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcMOv.jpg)
l was trying to creating an activity in android studion then l made a mistake added / at the end of the activity name so R.java keeps on showing me an error guys help me l have tried all my best.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Build -> Clean Project` this will resolve your problem. And don't go for mannual changes in `R.java` file it is auto generated by Android Studio.